# In bash, declare an alias that depends on current variable content

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I would like to declare an alias (in my `.bash_profile`) that will use the content (value) of a variable when the alias is *used*, not when it is defined. E.g.,

```
alias goSomeWhere="cd $BASE/somewhere"
```

`$BASE` is not set when the alias is defined, only when is it used. But, because `$BASE` is evaluated when the alias is defined (at login time), the `goSomeWhere` alias is interpreted as `cd /somewhere`.

How can I delay the evaluation of the variable until the alias is executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace both `"` by `'` or prefix `$` with a `\`.

Comment: backslash is the consistent solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`alias` is a builtin, not a keyword that could make Bash interpret the rest of the line in a different way than it normally does this. And normally double-quoted (or unquoted) variables are expanded by the shell before the command (or the builtin) is invoked. This happens in your case. Note the expansion is not limited to the part after `=`. I mean you can do this:

```sh
var1=alias
var2='foo=bar'
"$var1" "$var2"
```

and it will effectively create an alias that turns `foo` into `bar`. In your definition you want `$BASE` to be single-quoted, so it's not expanded.

Any alias replaces *text* with *text*. It's purely textual. As you want `goSomeWhere` to be replaced with literal

```
cd $BASE/somewhere
```

Wait. No, you don't want the above, [you want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) the below:

```
cd "$BASE/somewhere"
```

Your definition should be:

```
alias goSomeWhere='cd "$BASE/somewhere"'
```

See [*Parameter expansion (variable expansion) and quotes within quotes*](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690). The variable is single-quoted when the alias is defined, but properly double-quoted after the alias is expanded (which happens every time you use it).