# Parameter expansion (variable expansion) and quotes within quotes

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, sh

While working in a (Unix) shell, sometimes I need to double-quote single-quotes or vice versa, i.e. to write something like `"foo 'bar baz' moo"` or `'foo "bar baz" moo'`. This may be because

- the resulting string will be parsed *again* (like with `eval`, with a shell run by `watch`, with a shell run by `sshd` on some remote server etc.) and these inner quotes are crucial to distinguish actual arguments during this second parsing;
- or I just need the original argument to include quotes for whatever other reason.

Some ambiguity appears when instead of `bar baz` I have a variable, say `$variable`. This is [what POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02):

> 2.2.2 Single-Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single-quotes (`''`) shall preserve the literal value of each character within the single-quotes. A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes.
>
> 2.2.3 Double-Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double-quotes (`""`) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, <dollar-sign>, and <backslash>, as follows:
>
> `$`
>   The  shall retain its special meaning introducing parameter expansion […], a form of command substitution […], and arithmetic expansion […].
>
> […]

It's not exactly obvious which rule applies for `$variable` inside single-quotes inside double-quotes (or inside double-quotes inside single-quotes), therefore I'm asking:

1. Which rule applies to:

   - ```
     variable=123
     echo "'$variable'"
     ```
   - ```
     variable=123
     echo '"$variable"'
     ```

   <sup>(I'm aware this can be easily answered just by trying, it would be a reasonable research effort. I decided to put this effort into the community wiki answer below).</sup>
2. Are there any exceptions, quirks, surprises?

   <sup>(Please note there is a community wiki answer below. Instead of adding a separate answer with another exception or quirk, consider contributing to the community wiki one).</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which rule applies?

Just by trying:

- ```
  $ variable=123
  $ echo "'$variable'"
  '123'
  $
  ```
- ```
  $ variable=123
  $ echo '"$variable"'
  "$variable"
  $
  ```

So **the outer quotes matter**. Common shells behave in the same way: `sh`, `bash`, `dash`, `zsh`, … It's because of this general rule:

> If the current character is <backslash>, single-quote, or double-quote and it is not quoted, it shall affect quoting for subsequent characters up to the end of the quoted text.

[<sup>(source)</sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03)

Only the outer quotes are not quoted, the rule applies to them. The inner quotes are quoted, they do not affect subsequent characters.

---

> Are there any exceptions, quirks, surprises?

<sup>(Well, `echo` may introduce few surprises, see [*Why is `printf` better than `echo`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) Still, this is a separate issue. For readability the answer uses `echo` with a safe value of `$variable`).</sup>

1. The above code gives us either `'123'` or `"$variable"`. What if we need `"123"` or `'$variable'`?

   - To get `"123"`:

     ```
     variable=123
     echo "\"$variable\""
     #     ^^         ^^   escaped inner quotes
     ```

     or

     ```
     variable=123
     echo '"'"$variable"'"'
     #    1 12         23 3   outer quotes (numbered pairs)
     #     ^  ^^^^^^^^^  ^    quoted fragments
     ```
   - To get `'$variable'`:

     ```
     variable=123
     echo "'"'$variable'"'"
     #    1 12         23 3   outer quotes (numbered pairs)
     #     ^  ^^^^^^^^^  ^    quoted fragments
     ```
2. The question notices that `$` retains its special meaning in double-quotes. This is important:

   > The input characters within the quoted string that are also enclosed between `$(` and the matching `)` shall not be affected by the double-quotes, but rather shall define that command whose output replaces the `$(…)` when the word is expanded.

   [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)

   It means quoting within `$(…)` should be considered independently, despite the outer double-quotes. Indeed:

   ```
   $ variable=123
   $ echo "$(echo 'foo $variable')"
   $ #            ^             ^   single-quotes matter!
   foo $variable
   $
   ```

   (Note `echo $(stuff)` is [bad code in general](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690); it's here to *illustrate* the current issue).

   In these two cases:

   - `echo "'$variable'"` (tried way above)
   - `echo "$(echo 'foo $variable')"` (discussed here)

   there is `$variable` inside single-quotes inside double-quotes, but `$(…)` changes a lot. Similar situation with `` echo "`echo 'foo $variable'`" `` (although [`$(…)` and backticks are not exactly equivalent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/108618)).