# Need to expand a variable in a HEREDOC that is in quotes

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Is it possible to use a HEREDOC and get variable expansion to happen when the variable is in quotes?

Example: $package is an environment variable that is set before the script runs

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > out.json <<'EOF'
{
    "apps": [
    {
        "cwd":"/usr/local/$package"
    }
}
EOF
```

Expected output if $package="www"

```
{
    "apps": [
    {
        "cwd":"/usr/local/www"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR

Use `<<EOF` instead of `<<'EOF'`.

---

This is what POSIX says about here-documents [emphasis mine]:

> ```
> [n]<<word
>     here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> […]
>
> **If any part of `word` is quoted**, the delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on `word`, and **the here-document lines shall not be expanded**. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the `word` itself.
>
> **If no part of `word` is quoted, all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion**, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. […]

In your case `word` is `'EOF'` (quoted!), so `$package` inside the here-document is not expanded. Drop these quotes and you will get the desired result.

```
cat > out.json <<EOF
{
    "apps": [
    {
        "cwd":"/usr/local/$package"
    }
}
EOF
```

Note this has nothing to do with quotes that surround the variable inside the here-document.