# how to execute command in console of program (i.e. various databases) through shell/bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, database

I would like to have script that starts console (i.e. of database postgres or mongo) and to execute some commands that are known to work,

one of solutions is

```bsh
file.sh --> db.EXPECTED_COLLECTION.remove("_id":1234)

cat file.sh | mongo <EXPECTED_COLLECTION>
```

it feels like monkey patching (sure it can be closed in another script) so are there more "professional" ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat file.sh | mongo …` is [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), `<file.sh mongo …` is better.

<sup>Side note: why `.sh`? It doesn't matter to `mongo` or whatever, but people will expect `file.sh` to be a shell script. From now on I'm using `file1` instead.</sup>

[`man 1 mongo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mongo) gives an example: `mongo script1.js script2.js script3.js`, so I expect `mongo … file1` to work as well.

`#!/path/to/mongo` or `#!/usr/bin/env mongo` can be used as a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Use the shebang in `file1`, make the file executable (`chmod +x file1`) and run it directly (e.g. by typing `./file1` in its directory). Place `file1` in a directory specified in your `PATH` and you will be able to run it by simply calling `file1`.

Note a shebang specifies an interpreter and at most one additional argument. Technically you can add one argument (like your `<EXPECTED_COLLECTION>`) after `#!/path/to/mongo` (but not after `#!/usr/bin/env mongo` where `mongo` is the argument), but I would rather do everything in JavaScript below the shebang.

> you can specify the mongodb connection parameters inside of the javascript file using the `Mongo()` constructor.

<sup>([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting))</sup>

`psql` is somewhat different. A basic way to interpret a script is `psql -f file2` (`psql <file2` should also work, but see what [`man 1 psql`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/psql) says about it where it describes `-f`).

A shebang like `#!/path/to/psql -f` would work, if `psql` ignored lines starting with `#` (like e.g. `sh` does) or if it at least recognized `#!…` in the first line as a shebang and skipped the line. It doesn't. There are few tricks to circumvent this; see [*Shebang for `psql`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3995326/10765659).

---

One of the answers from the last link uses a here document in a shell script. This approach is quite powerful. An example of a Python script inside a Bash script is here: [*How to include python script inside a bash script?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184735/108618) Similarly you can pass an embedded script to `mongo …` (or to `psql -f -`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mongo … << 'EOF'
db.EXPECTED_COLLECTION.remove("_id":1234)
EOF
```

If you call *this* script `file.sh` then the `.sh` part will *not* be misleading. It is a shell script.

Note `<< EOF` instead of `<< 'EOF'` will allow you to [pass expanded variables](https://superuser.com/a/1437022/432690) from the shell to `mongo`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer