# Run shell script on remote machine with SSH using local environment variable

Tags: ssh, shell, environment-variables

I currently compute some environment variable on my local machine `$FOO`. Now, I have an SSH script which consists of a few commands, some of which use the environment variable `$FOO`, which is only set on my local machine.

I want to run those commands on the remote machine *but* I want to substitute the *local* version of `$FOO` so that when the SSH script runs on my remote machine it will use the local, computed value of `$FOO`. I need to do this because how the commands run on the remote machine depends on the local value of `$FOO` that I have computed.

I know that you can do `ssh user@remote < script.sh` to run the local shell script on the remote machine but I am unsure how to do that process but with my *local* `$FOO` environment variable as I mentioned above. I do not want to have to configure SSH on either the local or remote machines so `SendEnv` is not an option for me.

What is the best way to run those commands that I have in my shell script with the local environment variable `$FOO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know what shell should interpret the script. This example uses `sh`:

```
# somewhat flawed
ssh user@remote "FOO='$FOO' exec sh" < script.sh
```

The local shell will substitute `$FOO` because it's double-quoted ([it is](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690)). Single-quotes are for the remote shell (i.e. the original remote shell that `exec`s to the final `sh`).

Note `ssh` passes the whole command as a *string*. It will be interpreted on the remote side. If `$FOO` expands to a string containing one or more single-quotes, the whole command may misbehave. Code injection is possible.

To "disarm" possible single-quotes you can try this approach:

```
# still somewhat flawed
FOOx="$(printf '%s' "$FOO" | sed "s|'|'\"'\"'|g")"
ssh user@remote "FOO='$FOOx' exec sh" < script.sh
```

In my Debian 9 it changes every `'` in `$FOO` into `'"'"'` in `$FOOx`. Analyze quoting in the remote shell to see the center single-quote will survive literally.

I can do this without the extra variable:

```
# still somewhat flawed
ssh user@remote "FOO='$(printf '%s' "$FOO" | sed "s|'|'\"'\"'|g")' exec sh" < script.sh
```

It's not as firm as I wish. Problems:

- I think some implementations of `sed` may print a complete line (with trailing newline character) if their input is an incomplete line (without trailing newline character). Or `sed` can ignore an incomplete line. This is very important if the content of the variable doesn't end with a newline.
- `$()` removes all trailing newlines.

To deal with these I append `x` and a newline character before `sed`. The tool (regardless of implementation) should then accept everything, it should add nothing. Then `$()` will remove only the extra newline. I remove the extra `x` on the remote side. Like this:

```
# foolproof (AFAIK)
ssh user@remote "FOO='$(printf '%sx\n' "$FOO" | sed "s|'|'\"'\"'|g")'; FOO=\"\${FOO%x}\" exec sh" < script.sh
```

Notes:

- If your (local) `$FOO` expands to a string that contains no single-quotes for sure, then you can use the first, simplest command.
- If your local shell is Bash then you can replace single-quotes with `'"'"'` upon expansion like this:

  ```
  # foolproof (AFAIK), needs local Bash
  pattern="'"
  replacement="'\"'\"'"
  ssh user@remote "FOO='${FOO//$pattern/$replacement}' exec sh" < script.sh
  ```

  This solves the problem of single quotes and uses neither `$()` nor `sed`, so other mentioned problems doesn't appear. I used additional variables to avoid [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537823/108618).