# Can you pass multiple parameters to a bash function by using bash -c?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am using the `bash -c` command and a function:

```
fun ()
{
echo "$0"  ## it reads the parameter $i
}

for i in {1..5}
do
bash -c "fun" $i &
done
```

My question is can we pass multiple parameters to function by using `bash -c`? 
for example:

```
fun ()
{
echo "$0"  ## it reads the parameter $i
}

var="string"  #variable

for i in {1..5}
do
bash -c "fun" $i $var &
done
```

Comment: Assuming you're running your program in BASH (please confirm it), why do you need `bash -c`? Why not simply `fun $i`?

Comment: @quasimodo, when ever i do ```fun $i &``` run in background for multiple inputs, the $$(which is in the function) returns the same value, but  when I use bash -c  the $$(in the function) workes gives the diff values. thats why i am using the ```bash -c```

Comment: Use [`$BASHPID`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484445/108618) and stop this `bash -c` nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Have you actually run the code? Both snippets return `fun: command not found` and this is the problem you need to address first.

<sup>Unless you managed to export `fun` as a function, or defined it *elsewhere* in a way that allows the inner `bash` to recognize the command (I will not elaborate). This situation would be quite misleading, thus unfortunate in the context of further issues.</sup>

Let's start with straightforward code that does what you probably wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun ()
{
   echo "$1"
}

for i in {1..5}
do
   fun "$i" &
done
```

If you get numbers not in sequence, it's because of `&`. I used `&` here because it was in your original code.

Your definition of the function is syntactically OK. My definition uses `$1` instead of `$0`, we'll get to it. To use a function you just call its name, with or without arguments. In our case:

```
fun
fun arg1
fun arg1 arg2
```

Inside a function `$1`, `$2`, … expand to respective arguments. You use `$@` (or `$*` if you know what you are doing) to get all the arguments. You use `$#` to get the number of arguments. This is very similar to a situation where `fun` is a shell script.

`$0` inside a function is `$0` of the main shell. It has nothing to do with arguments passed to the function.

You can run the function in a subshell:

```
( fun arg1 )
```

or in the background (which implicitly runs it in a subshell as well):

```
fun arg1 &
```

If `fun` is a function in the main shell then these subshells will also know what to do when the command is `fun`. On the other hand a shell started with `bash -c` has no idea of `fun`.

<sup>Again: unless you managed to `export` … or …</sup>

In your case `bash -c` is rather an obstacle. I see no point in using it. It is possible to make it work but it would be cumbersome. Still, your *explicit* question is:

> can we pass multiple parameters to function by using `bash -c`?

We can. Cumbersome example below. Note the function is slightly different (for educational reason). I also dropped `&` because it only obfuscates the results.

```
#!/bin/bash

fun ()
{
   echo "$2"
}

export -f fun
var="string"

for i in {1..5}
do
   bash -c 'fun "$2" "$1"' inner-bash "$i" "$var"
done
```

Exporting a function from Bash to Bash is possible and we just did it. Exporting a function from Bash to another shell is impossible, unless the shell tries to be compatible and deliberately interprets some environment variables as functions.

`fun "$2" "$1"` is single-quoted, so in the main shell `"$2"` and `"$1"` are not expanded (being single-quoted, [they are *not* double-quoted](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690)). In the context of the inner `bash` these `$2` and `$1` are double-quoted and they expand to parameters provided after `inner-bash` (which is an arbitrary name here).

See what happens to a number stored as `$i`:

- it's `$i` in the context of the main shell;
- then it's `$1` in the context of the inner shell;
- then it's `$2` in the context of the function in the inner shell.

There is no advantage of using `bash -c` here, only inconvenience. Do not complicate your code this way.

One more thing: [double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: thank you for valuable answer, I am using $0 because `bash -c` takes from 0th value instead of 1st value that we are passing.

Comment: I asked this sample question because in my actual script I am runing the function 8 times(in a loop for diff files) and we will have 8 different subshells, so i am using `bash -c`.

Comment: @saiprudhvi From 0th for good reason. See `man 1 bash` where it describes `-c`. `$0` is "used in warning and error messages". Suppose you want to pass the string `date`. Invoke `bash -c 'nonexistent "$1"' my_bash date`; The error is `my_bash: nonexistent: command not found`. You know at once the problem is with `my_bash`. Invoke `bash -c 'nonexistent "$0"' date`; the error is `date: nonexistent: command not found`. It suggests `date` may be the command that is not found; and you wonder where the error came from. Therefore use some name to populate `$0` and provide actual arguments after it.

Comment: @saiprudhvi It will be even worse if instead of a fixed string (like `date`) you provide an expanded variable. You may get errors (or warnings) starting from "random" strings that make absolutely no sense in errors. Very confusing. Your original code yields not only `fun: command not found` but like `1: fun: command not found` or `5: fun: command not found`. It's because `$i` from the main shell becomes `$0` in the inner shell.