# How can we separate substring by using delimiter in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have the string below:

```
/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand
```

I am beginner to Linux. How can I separate by using "|" as delimiter and assign in a variable?
I am passing the entire string as parameter and need to split\cut the fields separately.

For example:

```
function()
{
while read -r record; do
## here i need the fields to cut the fields and assign to a variable #####
done < $0 
}

bash -c function "/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand"
```

When I tried the above example it throws an error `$0: ambiguous redirect`.

Comment: It makes little sense to *separate* and store in *a* variable. Unless it's an array; or *multiple* variables. Or do you want to change one separator into another (e.g. a newline)? Do you need the variable(s) in child process(es)? or only in Bash? What is your research so far and what have you tried? Is the string hardcoded? available in a file? in another variable? or generated by some tool? Please [edit] the question and be more specific about the usage case.

Comment: I need the variables in the child. i am passing the entire string to child and need to seperate and assign to variable. i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` to separate using delimiter

In the following example we replace `|` by `newline`

```
variable=$(echo "/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand" | tr "|" "\n")

echo $variable
```

---

You can also use

```
echo yourtext | tr -d "|"
```

---

See [tr command](https://shapeshed.com/unix-tr/)

Answer (score 0):

So many issues beside the main one.

1. `ambiguous redirect` is because [your code lacks double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775870/10765659).
2. Redirection with `<` takes data from a file. Your string does not point to a file (path). In Bash you can take data from a string with `<<<`.
3. `function` is a reserved word. There is a way to name a function `function` but its further use is inconvenient.
4. (terminology in your comment) Function is not a child.
5. One calls a function by its name, not with `bash -c`. [My answer to your other question](https://superuser.com/a/1523581/432690) applies.
6. Then the first argument is referred to as `$1`, not `$0`.

This code works, although I'm not sure it's exactly what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

split_string ()
{
   readarray -t arrayv < <(tr '|' '\n' <<< "$1")
}

split_string '/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand'

# now arrayv is an array variable (indexed from 0)
# retrieving few values
echo "${arrayv[0]}"
echo "${arrayv[5]}"
echo "${arrayv[9]}"
```

Notes:

- You double-quoted the string. Remember a string in double-quotes undergoes certain expansions. Your string does not contain anything that would/could be expanded (e.g. `$`), so double-quotes are OK in this particular case. In general use single-quotes to suppress expansions.
- `readarray` is a synonym for `mapfile`. Invoke `help mapfile` to learn.
- Other research fodder: [`<<<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings), [`<( … )`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution), [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays).
- There is no way to `export` an array variable to the environment.
- We could tell `readarray` to use `|` as delimiter:

  ```
   readarray -t -d '|' arrayv <<< "$1"
  ```

  but then the last "field" would include a trailing newline character (it would appear because of how `<<<` works). I turn all delimiters to newlines with `tr`, then `readarray` uses its default setting (newlines as delimiters).
- Spaces don't belong to delimiters, they become parts of the stored values. Use `sed` instead of `tr` to turn substrings of delimiters with adjacent spaces into single newline characters. The `readarray …` line will be:

  ```
  readarray -t arrayv < <(sed 's/ *| */\n/g' <<< "$1")
  ```
- If you're going to use the function just once, you don't need a function at all. This line (outside of any function) will do the job:

  ```
  readarray -t arrayv < <(tr '|' '\n' <<< '/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand')
  ```

  I defined a function (and then used it just once) because you tried to define one.
- If your input string consists of a fixed number of fields and the fields have meaning, it may be good to assign them to different (non-array, regular) variables whose names have meaning. Example:

  ```
  IFS='|' read -r path1 path2 path3 path4 path5 ip path6 wtf1 wtf2 wtf3 extra < <(sed 's/ *| */|/g' <<< '/a585/app/data/CCN_text/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file07 | /svr00c8/n585 | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/CCN_text | /a585/app/data/muttrc | 153.2.254.229 | /a001/odbi_land/ondemand/download/scriptload | DVLP | cmodappl | ondemand')
  echo "$ip"
  echo "$wtf3"
  ```

  Specific notes:

  - Here we explicitly use `|` as delimiter. When we use `read`, the trailing newline (that appears because of how certain redirections and tools work) is not only harmless, it's required.
  - I added the `extra` variable. If there are more fields than expected then the excessive fields will occupy `extra`. Without `extra` they would affect `$wtf3`.
  - You can `export` these variables.
- If you're going to manipulate files/streams containing (many) records in a form of `foo|bar|baz|…` (or `foo | bar | baz | …` or similar) then get familiar with `awk`.