# notify-send Works From Shell Session, Not From Script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, reminder, at, dunst

I am using `at` in coordination with `notify-send`/`dunst` as a form of reminders for myself. In an interactive `bash` session, doing:

```
$ echo 'notify-send "Test"' | at 12:45PM
```

works just fine and I see the notification pop up at exactly 12:45PM as expected. However, in a script like:

```
$ cat ~/.local/bin/remind
#!/bin/bash

echo 'notify-send "$1"' | at "$2"

$ remind "Test" "12:45PM"
```

I don't see the notification pop up.

The job is registered with `at`, as seen by:

```
$ at -l
```

so I'm not sure what the problem could be. `notify-send` works just fine outside of the script, and `at` has correctly found the job, but I still don't see a popup when trying with the second method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two levels of interpretation:

1. `bash` running your script interprets the whole command. Here `$1` is [single-quoted](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690), so it is not expanded. The string containing literal `"$1"` gets to `at`.
2. When the time comes, `at` runs the previously echoed string using `sh`. Now `$1` is double-quoted and it gets expanded to an empty string because this `sh` apparently runs without arguments. Whatever you provided to the script is long gone. The final command is as if you typed `notify-send ""` in a shell. Run it and see what happens.

A basic fix is to swap the quotes:

```
echo "notify-send '$1'" | at "$2"
```

This way `bash` will expand `$1` and the result will be single-quoted later, when `sh` runs. The approach is not very robust; the code will break if you inject a single quote. Yet in many cases it will work.

---

A more robust way is like this:

```
#/bin/bash

t="$1"
shift
m="$*"

<<<"notify-send ${m@Q}" at "$t"
```

The main point is using the `${variable@Q}` syntax. It makes Bash expand the variable *and properly single-quote* the result, so it can be safely parsed later (by `sh` in this case).

Note I obtain time from the first argument. The idea is to be able to call the script without inconvenient quotes, like this:

```
remind 15:10 Go to Yuma
```