# Why does my bash script not navigate properly?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

My final goal for this script is to:

1. Visit folder in loop
2. find the `descriptor.mod`
3. Rename it to its folder name
4. Relocate it to a specific folder
5. repeat

Currently, when I am trying to visit the folder I get this error

```
$ . a.sh
bash: cd: 'a.sh/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 1/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 2/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 3/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 4/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 5/': No such file or directory
haha
bash: cd: 'Folder 6/': No such file or directory
haha
```

This is my code.
There are six folders named `Folder {number}`

```
for f in *
do
    cd "'$f/'"
    echo "haha"
    cd ..
done

cd "E:\School\LINUX"
```

EDIT: Found it.
I changed `for f in *` to `for f in */`

Comment: Strangely you don't get any error from `cd "E:\School\LINUX"`. Is `E:\School\LINUX` a directory? Note in Linux this name is a single component, not a path with many components.

Answer (score 4):

The command `cd "'$f/'"` contains outer double-quotes that will be removed by the shell after they serve they purpose of quoting. The inner single-quotes will survive and get to `cd` as parts of the argument. (More about quotes within quotes here: [Parameter expansion (variable expansion) and quotes within quotes](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).)

In effect you're trying to `cd` to e.g. `'Folder 1/'` with *literal* single-quotes, while the existing target is `Folder 1/`. There is no `'Folder 1/'` directory.

---

Additionally `*` matches non-directories as well. `a.sh` is the script. After you add `/` *and* single-quotes, you're trying to `cd` to `'a.sh/'`. There is no such directory.

Having failed to `cd` into this non-directoriy, you then subsequently also run `cd ..`, which will take you out of the starting directory, and into its parent. From here, the entities that the original `*` matched are no longer visible, and so all further attempts to `cd` fail too... in fact, each subsequent failed `cd` will take you up one directory.

---

You need `for f in */` to iterate over directories only (but note `*` doesn't match dotfiles). Then you don't need to add `/` because the trailing slash appears from the expansion of `$f` (although another trailing slash shouldn't break anything). And you absolutely shouldn't add single-quotes to the argument of `cd`. The relevant line should be `cd "$f"`.

---

You could use a loop like the following to iterate through all entities, skipping non-directories, and handling `cd` errors correctly:

- `[ ! -d "${f}" ] && continue` to skip non-directories (note: this will still match symlinks that point at directories)
- `cd "${f}" || continue` to skip directories we can't enter (e.g: permissions)
- `pushd "${f}"` / `popd` to avoid relative `cd` return attempts

```bsh
for f in *; do
    # skip non-directories
    [ ! -d "$f" ] && continue

    # skip processing for directories we can't enter (e.g: permissions)
    pushd "$f" || continue

    echo "hi"
    pwd

    popd
done
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer hasn't been excepted, it seems pretty comprehensive!