# Grep with a variable in a script

Tags: bash, grep

I have this code that returns the number of files in a directory with the name wordpress.*.tar.gz

This code works `NUM_BACKUPS="$(ls -l ${POOL_PATH}/${BACKUP_PATH} | grep -c '\wordpress.*.tar.gz$')"`

but I want to replace wordpress with a variable in my bash script

I've tried `NUM_BACKUPS="$(ls -l ${POOL_PATH}/backup/${JAIL} | grep -c '\${JAIL}.*.tar.gz$')"`

but it doesn't work

Comment: Useful links: [Parameter expansion and quotes within quotes](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690) (quirk 2; note `${POOL_PATH}/backup/${JAIL}` is not [properly quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) inside `$()`, while `${JAIL}` is single-quoted), [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${JAIL}` is not getting expanded in the argument to `grep` because it's in single quotes.    You could switch the single quotes to double quotes (and change `\$` to just `$`), but that's kind of fragile.  A more robust solution would be to do this entirely with globbing and bash arrays:

```
shopt -s nullglob
BACKUP_FILES=( "${POOL_PATH}/backup/${JAIL}/${JAIL}"*.tar.gz )
NUM_BACKUPS=${#BACKUP_FILES[@]}
```

You need `nullglob` to handle the case where the glob doesn't match any files.  Without `nullglob`, you'd end up with `NUM_BACKUPS` set to 1 if you didn't have any files.

Note that the glob special characters (`*` in your case) have to be *outside* the double quotes in order to expand.  But you want to keep double quotes around the variables in case they contain any whitespace.