# How to pass all arguments to a script called by /bin/bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that I want it to receive a number of variable arguments and pass them to the execution of another script, but I'm only being able to pass the first argument set by the first call.

My script (`nodetool_improved`) looks like this:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password $@"
```

If I call it like:

```
$ nodetool_improved status
```

Then `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool` receives `status`, and the output looks OK. But if I call my script like:

```
$ nodetool_improved help status
```

Then the output instead of showing the help for the `status` option, just shows the help for all options, which is effectively the same as calling:

```
$ /usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool help
```

That means that `help status` is not being passed to `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool`. Only `help`.

How can I change my `nodetool_improved` script so that all arguments are passed to `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool`?

**Some other info**

- Nodetool is a tool to manage Apache Cassandra: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/help.html
- `cassandra` user is nologin

**Some things I've tried and which don't work:**

---

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password -- '$@'"
```

Error:

```
status': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
status': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

---

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password "$@"' -- "$@"
```

Error:

Only the `status` gets picked up. The output is the same as if I called it like:

```
/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool status
```

Comment: I think I managed to simplify the solution. The previous one was somewhat flawed in the  subject of `--`. See the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1601876/revisions) to learn what was added.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash under "special parameters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c \
   'exec /usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool \
    -u cassandra \
    -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password \
    "$@"' \
   -- my-inner-shell -- "$@"
```

Or even

```
sudo su cassandra -s /usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -- \
    -u cassandra \
    -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password \
    "$@"
```

---

#### Analysis

At first let's explicitly state that in your commands `sudo su` runs `su` and passes all the remaining arguments to it verbatim. Then `su cassandra -s /bin/bash` runs `/bin/bash` and passes all the remaining arguments to it verbatim. These steps are irrelevant to your issue. The important thing is what the inner Bash gets.

Your first command

> ```
> sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password $@"
> ```

is very flawed. After `sudo` and `su` do their thing, `bash` runs as if user `cassandra` did:

```
# flawed
/bin/bash -c "something $@"
```

The immediate cause of your problem is the fact that double quoted `$@` gets expanded by the outer shell before `sudo` (and `su` and the inner `bash`) even starts. Double-quoted `$@` expands to (possibly) separate arguments. The first of them gets concatenated with the string (if any) preceding `$@` in double-quotes; the last of them gets concatenated with the string (if any) following `$@` in double-quotes. When you pass `help` and `status`, it's as if user `cassandra` run:

```
/bin/bash -c "something help" "status"
```

and *only* `something help` is the code. That's why `status` was ignored.

The version that uses `"something '$@'"` gets `$@` expanded by the outer shell as well ([the outer quotes matter](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690)) and results in a command like:

```
/bin/bash -c "something 'help" "status'"
```

which is even worse because `something 'help` interpreted as code is syntactically invalid; there is unmatched single-quote there, hence `unexpected EOF`.

In general allowing some outer tool to expand anything in a string that becomes code for the inner tool is safe only if you totally control the outcome of the expansion. If it's not known in advance nor sanitized (which may be hard) then you'll have code injection vulnerability. E.g. when you run this

```
bash -c "echo $variable"
```

and the `$variable` happens to expand to `; rm -f important_file` then you will effectively run

```
bash -c "echo; rm -f important_file"
```

You cannot fix this by quoting. E.g. this

```
bash -c "echo '$variable'"
```

will miserably fail if `$variable` expands to `'; rm -f important_file'` (where single-quotes belong to the variable).

Your code was flawed not only because `$@` could expand to multiple arguments which resulted in all but one being ignored. The argument that was not ignored was able to inject code.

This is a general problem, not only in a shell+shell scenario. [The outer tool can e.g. be `find`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/108618)

---

#### Towards the solution

The right thing to do is to pass positional parameters of the outer shell as positional parameters (not code) to the inner shell. This try of yours:

> ```
> sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password "$@"' -- "$@"
> ```

is almost the right thing.

This is as if user `cassandra` run:

```
/bin/bash -c 'something "$@"' -- "$@"
```

In the subject of quoting and avoiding code injection this is very good. The code is single-quoted, so the outer shell does not expand the first `$@`. In the code interpreted by the inner shell `$@` is double-quoted [as it should be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). This part is fine.

The problem is in `-- "$@"`. Bash follows [this convention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) where `--` option denotes end of options. It's good to use it in case something that looks like an option appears from the expansion of the second `$@` (performed by the outer shell). The first non-option argument following `-c 'shell code'` becomes `$0` in the inner shell. What follows becomes `$1`, `$2` etc. In your case these come from the expansion of the second `$@`, but the outer `$1` becomes the inner `$0`, the outer `$2` becomes the inner `$1` etc. That's why when you passed `help` and `status`, `help` "disappeared".

The solution is to provide a "dummy" argument that will become the inner `$0`. This way the outer `$1` will become the inner `$1` etc. Such "dummy" argument is not really a dummy, it has its purpose. Please read [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

So the snippet should be like:

```
/bin/bash -c 'something "$@"' -- some-name "$@"
```

Now you want to add `sudo su …` in front. I tested `sudo`: in general it supports `--`, but after what looks like a command (e.g. `su` in `sudo su …`) it neither needs nor interprets `--`. It's different with `su` itself. At first I thought `su` uses everything after `-s` to build a command. Then I thought it uses everything after `-c` as arguments. In any of these cases `--` wouldn't be needed and I expected `su` to behave somewhat like `sudo`.

But no. In my Debian 10 this command:

```
su kamil A -c B -s /bin/echo C -c D E -- -c F G
```

works as if user `kamil` run:

```
/bin/echo -c D A C E -c F G
```

The option-argument to `-s` can be any executable. `su` searches for options for itself until it encounters `--`, no matter if beyond `-s` or `-c`. The latest `-c` before `--` "wins". Then the tool passes its own option-argument found after `-c` to the executable along with a leading `-c` argument, followed by any arguments it didn't recognize as options or option-arguments to itself.

This means you need `--` destined for `su` to actually pass `--` to the shell. You want something like:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c 'something "$@"' -- -- some-name "$@"
```

I've encountered `su` that in some (not all) circumstances "consumed" `-- --` instead of `--`. It was probably a weird bug. Separating the two double-dashes with another argument (if possible) seemed to be a workaround. So this may be little better:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c 'something "$@"' -- some-name -- "$@"
```

And because the inner shell is used only to run a single command, then maybe his:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c 'exec something "$@"' -- some-name -- "$@"
```

But since `-s` accepts any executable and you can pass any argument to it (even without it supporting `-c`), you can get rid of `/bin/bash` completely:

```
sudo su cassandra -s something -- "$@"
```

The two solutions in the beginning of the answer are adaptations of the above two "templates".

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. It'll still be a few weeks before I can test this out due to devops pipeline, but since the `cassandra` user is a nologin user, don't I need to explicitly say which shell to use with `-s /bin/bash`?

Comment: @PedroGordo I don't know why you'd like `su` to spawn a shell instead of running `nodetool` directly. If you know then feel free to use the version with `-s /bin/bash`.

Comment: I was under the impression that changing user for a nologin user required a new shell, but I guess I was wrong. I'm still learning my way around Linux. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another possible solution. In case you can't or don't want to use sudo/su. This solution works for me.

I know eval is evil. But sometimes you need the help of evil forces :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
$command='ls'
$args='-lah'

eval $(printf "bash -c '%q %q'" "${command}" "${args}")
```