# Overriding calls of application/command in specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I would like to run specific application in specific folders only. For example for `vint` application

```
$ cd /workspace/vim-plugin
$ vint ftplugin/terraform.vim
```

Should run `docker exec -i vim-plugin sh -c "vint ftplugin/terraform.vim"` in others folders `vint` should mean something different or even "command not found".

Solution I'm using now is `direnv` to add ./.bin folder to the PATH and generate shell scripts in that folder which override or add possibility to run specific app. In example above it would be /workspace/vim-plugin/.bin/vint which in simplify version looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker exec -i vim-plugin sh -c "vint $@"
```

It's works more or less as supposed to but there are some annoyance with generating this scripts, and parsing script params (single or double quotation params).

My question is, do you have different ideas how to approach this problem in Gnu/Linux environment, shell bash/zsh? Maybe solution from BusyBox when you have one application and just link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annoyance with "parsing script params (single or double quotation params)" is because you're not passing `$@` in the right way. This is your way:

> ```
> docker exec -i vim-plugin sh -c "vint $@"
> ```

The shell interpreting your script expands double-quoted `$@` and the things get messy. See the analysis and what follows in [my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1601876/432690). The problem is very similar. Your code after an improvement:

```
docker exec -i vim-plugin sh -c 'exec vint "$@"' -- vint-sh "$@"
```

I don't know `docker` *at all*, but since it can run `sh -c …` then probably it can run `vint …` *directly*. If so, then there is no reason for `sh` in the first place. The code becomes:

```
docker exec -i vim-plugin vint "$@"
```

Hopefully `docker exec …` does not interpret options after the first argument that looks like a command (here: `sh` or `vint`). See the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1601876/432690) where I point out `sudo` and `su` behave differently in this subject. Hopefully `docker exec` is similar to `sudo`. [This documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) makes me believe so.

After `docker` is started, the shell interpreting the script seems no longer needed. Instead of running the command and waiting, it can replace itself with the command; with `exec`:

```
exec docker …
```

For this you don't need `bash`, `sh` should start faster:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
exec docker exec -i vim-plugin vint "$@"
```

Now your approach with `./.bin` in `PATH` should work. Still adding `./.bin` is similarly flawed as [adding `.` to `PATH`](https://superuser.com/q/156582/432690). A better approach is to create a single directory for wrapper scripts, add its absolute path to `PATH` as the first entry and put a single wrapper for `vint` there. The wrapper can test its `$PWD` (with `if`, `elif`; or with `case`) and act accordingly. Program any logic you want. It may turn out you will be able to implement your desired logic in a simpler way in `bash` than in `sh`; so you may prefer `bash` in the shebang after all.

Comment: Thank @Kamil Maciorowski, I don't know why I tried to use shell inside container instead of just running application directly. I still use "bin" folder per project but I keep there only links to shim script (dockenv-cmd). It works quite well with direnv. Full solution is [here](https://github.com/mandos/dockenv)