# mysql connection from bash shell with special characters in password errors out

Tags: linux, bash, mysql, shell-script, characters

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
MYSQLTEMPPWD=`grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk 'NF{ print 
$NF }'`;
MYSQLPWD=`echo "'$MYSQLTEMPPWD'"`;
echo $MYSQLPWD;
CONNINFO="mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=$MYSQLPWD"
$CONNINFO <<EOF
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Welcome!23';
show databases;
status;
EOF
set +x
exit
```

```
>  ./test.sh
++ grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
++ awk 'NF{ print $NF }'
+ MYSQLTEMPPWD='>fjkIyu#K7T?'
++ echo ''\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
+ MYSQLPWD=''\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
+ echo ''\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
'>fjkIyu#K7T?'
+ CONNINFO='mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password='\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
+ mysql --host=localhost --user=root '--password='\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
+ set +x
```

Problem i face is for some reasons during the execution step single quote is getting added before password parameter
('--password='''>fjkIyu#K7T?'''').

Tried almost all possible ways based on the blogs, nothing helped sofar.

Anyone please suggest. Thanks...

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (Short summary: don't try to put commands in variables, it doesn't work right.)

Answer (score 1):

In the following part of the feedback enabled with `set -x`:

> ```
> '--password='\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''
> ```

all but two single-quotes are only to present this string to you. [This is how `set -x` works.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118466/108618) This is just an artifact of the way the shell implements the execution trace; it doesn't alter the way the argument is ultimately passed to the command.

`mysql` gets exactly this: `--password='>fjkIyu#K7T?'`. There are two literal single-quote characters in this string because *you* added them. Here:

> ```
> MYSQLPWD=`echo "'$MYSQLTEMPPWD'"`
> ```

First of all, `echo` here is a mistake. It has [its own problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) but the weirdest thing is you echo one variable only to capture the result (using backticks) and store in another variable. If you want to create another variable with the same value then it's as simple as:

```
MYSQLPWD="$MYSQLTEMPPWD"
```

Or if you want to add single-quotes to the stored string:

```
MYSQLPWD="'$MYSQLTEMPPWD'"
```

(see [*Parameter expansion and quotes within quotes*](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690)).

I think I know why you thought you needed these single-quotes. This brings us to the other issue. You store *code* in a variable:

> ```
> CONNINFO="mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=$MYSQLPWD"
> ```

and then execute the expanded variable:

> ```
> $CONNINFO …
> ```

In general [you should double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). But if you double-quoted then `"$CONNINFO"` would expand to a single word which is not a command. So you don't quote to let word splitting work. But then whatever `$MYSQLPWD` expanded to (and is now stored inside `CONNINFO`) undergoes word splitting and filename generation. I suspect you enclosed the actual password in single-quotes in hope to prevent this. The problem is quotes that appear from an expanded variable are not special, they are not interpreted by the shell, they are not removed. Not only the single-quotes you added don't prevent word splitting or filename generation at this point; they go to `mysql` as parts of one of the arguments it gets.

These quotes would matter and disappear if you let the (or a) shell evaluate expanded (and properly double-quoted) `$CONNINFO` *again*.

The current shell will evaluate expanded `$CONNINFO` again if you use `eval "$CONNINFO"`, but [don't do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Another shell will evaluate expanded `$CONNINFO` again if you use `bash -c "$CONNINFO"` (or `sh -c …` or whatever shell), it will be about as bad as `eval`.

Note a single-quote character in `$MYSQLTEMPPWD` can pair with the opening single-quote you added. When interpreted again, some parts of the password will be unquoted. This can lead to a syntax error, code injection and other flaws.

Variables are simply not meant to store code. Why don't you keep it simple? Like this:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password="$MYSQLTEMPPWD" <<EOF
…
```

This way you need no `MYSQLPWD` nor `CONNINFO`; and what should be quoted is quoted.

OK, maybe the code in question is just an example and you think you really need to store code in a variable in your actual, more complex script. Then please read [*How can we run a command stored in a variable?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618)

---

Additional notes:

- Consider [lowercase variable names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).
- My answer ignores the `grep … | awk …` part which probably can be improved, but it's a different story.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support.

My intention is to connect to the mysql database and run few basic queries. I dont have any mandate to store the code in a variable and to execute it.
I just did that to confirm the mysql connection syntax is correct or not.

Here is the simple script that is executed now. 

`#!/bin/bash
set -x 
MYSQLTEMPPWD=`grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk 'NF{ print $NF }'`;
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password="$MYSQLTEMPPWD" <<EOF
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Welcome!23';
show databases;
status;
EOF
set +x
exit`

Comment: But still you can see the single quote ' before the password parameter ('--password)

`./test.sh
++ grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
++ awk 'NF{ print $NF }'
+ MYSQLTEMPPWD='>fjkIyu#K7T?'
+ mysql --host=localhost --user=root '--password=>fjkIyu#K7T?'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.
+ set +x`

Comment: The correct syntax which should get executed is 
`mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password='>fjkIyu#K7T?'`

Please see, if any changes i need to make it in the code.

Comment: @80sdba In the command line `'--password=>fjkIyu#K7T?'` and `--password='>fjkIyu#K7T?'` are equivalent. IMO you're executing exactly what you think you want. `set -x` prints the first form because [this is how it works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118466/108618). Earlier you got `'--password='\''>fjkIyu#K7T?'\'''` which was a sub-optimal representation of a string with actual single-quotes in it.

Comment: @80sdba Frankly I interpreted your "single quote is getting added before password parameter" as referring to the single-quote before the password string (i.e. `\'` after `=` in the output printed because of `set -x`). I thought the literal quotes before and after the password string should not be there. I still do think so. But now I think you referred to the single-quote before `--password`. The link in my previous comment explains this one. You were/are concerned with quotes that don't matter. If you're still getting `access denied` then probably the credentials are wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your guidance. Have tried with another method to use the config file to store the password and retrieved it from there, it worked. Please find the below code. Learnt many good information from your answers above. Thanks again...

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
MYSQLTEMPPWD=`grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk 'NF{ print $NF }'`;
cat > .my.cnf <<EOF
[mysql]
user=root
password=$MYSQLTEMPPWD
EOF
chmod 0600 .my.cnf
mysql --connect-expired-password <<EOF
#mysql --host=localhost --user=root <<EOF
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Welcome!23';
show databases;
status;
EOF
exit`

Comment: @80sdba I expanded my answer to cover the topic of single-quotes printed by `set -x` (nothing beyond what has already been said in comments; it's just I decided this should be in the answer). [Does it answer your question now?](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)